# How can I produce a situation when $EUID is different than $UID?

Tags: linux, sh, uuid

It might be a silly question but I am not understanding `EUID` and `UID` correctly.
The description of real ID and effective ID is clear and I get it. Based on what I have found on Google and ebooks, when using `su`, `sudo` or `SUID`, effective ID should change. Also, to my understanding `UID` in Bash should contain real ID and `EUID` should contain effective ID.

My assumption is `EUID` and `UID` should be different when I am using `su`, `sudo` or `SUID` but whenever I try `echo $EUID` and `echo $UID` the result of both are the same.
Also, I tried `id -u` and `id -r -u` and again they are always the same.

Could someone explain to me at when and what situation exactly `$EUID` and `$UID` are different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default bash drops the privileges. There is a special privileged mode `set -p`.

```
# copy bash executable
$ sudo cp /usr/bin/bash ./bash
# set the suid mode
$ chmod +s ./bash
$ ls -l bash
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 903504 05-29 23:48 ./bash*
# run it
$ ./bash -p -c 'echo $UID $EUID'
1000 0
```

Comment: To add to this, since both `sudo` and `su` have the setuid bit set, they both start with euid=0 and uid=youruser. However, they set both uid and euid to the target user before running commands, so you can't use them. The way to do it is to create a suid copy of a shell that both A. supports the (non-standard) EUID/UID variables, and B. doesn't or can be made not to drop privileges for security reasons. This could be `ksh`, `zsh` or `bash -p`.

Comment: Hello @thatotherguy, what is a "suid copy" of a shell? Thanks

Comment: A shell binary with the suid bit set, such as the one created in the example in this answer